# weird issue : jsf inside jsp not working

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I have created web-application using JSF 2.0 & JSP and facing some weird problem.

I have page in JSF where I have included JSP page. code are as below.

```
<o:resourceInclude path="detailedReports.jsp" />
```

Where o is omnifaces. `xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"`

Now in JSP (detailedReports.jsp) I have code as below.

```
<h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
    <h:commandLink value="Take Me To Some Page" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.moveToApplicantRegisterPage()}" />
</h:form>
```

`moveToApplicantRegisterPage()` have below code

```
public String moveToApplicantRegisterPage() {
    editedData = 1;
    return takeMeToAnotherPage("registerForPatentss");
}
```

When I click on `Take Me To Some Page` link, I get directed to `detailedReports.jsp` and not to `registerForPatentss.xhtml`.

Any reason why this is happening? What should I do to get redirected to `registerForPatentss.xhtml`.

**Note:** While redirecting to `registerForPatentss.xhtml`, I also need to set the data of `int editedData` to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any solution. So what I did is, take JSP in JSF i.e. I re-wrote JSP content in JSF Format. So now I don't have any JSP page.

All is working perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a rendering problem related to mixing two different view technologies (JSP and facelets).

Comment: o:resourceInclude is designed for that purpose.

Comment: Is it designed to allow you to embed facelets inside your JSP as well?